Are the threats made by members of the USA's Senate to the International Criminal Court chief prosecutor an abuse of power?
A number of United States senators have signed a letter accusing the International Criminal Court's chief prosecutor, Karim Khan, of politicised attack on Israel as an excuse for issuing arrest warrants against senior Israeli officials (Times of Israel):

“Target Israel, and we will target you,” the senators, led by Sen. Tom Cotton, warned in the letter. “Such actions are illegitimate and lack legal basis, and, if carried out, will result in severe sanctions against you and your institution.”
Sens. Mitch McConnell (minority leader), Rick Scott, Tim Scott, Ted Cruz, and Marco Rubio also signed the letter, amid increasing concern in Israel that the UN court could issue arrest warrants for senior political and military officials over the nearly-seven-month-old war in Gaza, including against Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu, Defense Minister Yoav Gallant, and IDF Chief of Staff Lt. Gen. Herzi Halevi.

Later, Khan posted a public message demanding a cessation to intimidation (etc) (Financial Times):

Karim Khan, the ICC prosecutor, demanded in a post on X that “all attempts to impede, intimidate, or improperly influence officials cease immediately”, without naming any specific state or officials. The ICC’s “independence and impartiality” were undermined “when individuals threaten to retaliate against the court or against court personnel”, he wrote.

My question is: what are the implications of this letter - does it pose legitimate threat, or is it an empty threat? And if it were legitimate, would it be an abuse of power by the US Senate?

Perhaps the term "abuse of power" is a sloppy word choice in the Question. Although I might even argue that US sanctions applied in foreign countries, once they become extraterritorial, and especially secondary sanctions that are extraterritorial, are an unlawful act of coercion in the place they target - since there's no legal theory at all that can trace back that exercise of power by the US to any consent (not even impled by some social contract theory) by the targeted parties - and in this case is clearly contrary to the laws or treaties of the foreign jurisdiciton (i.e. Rome Statute).

What's being abused is the extraordinary power of the US over the Western financial system, which allows the US Treasury to basically shut down any financial activity in the West, and in much of the world besides. Thankfully this outrageous state of affairs is slowly but surely coming to an end.

@PeteW I'd love suggestions for alternatives to "abuse of power" that fit with the spirit of the question. Indeed I was considering "intimidation" and "coercion" to "influence justice decisions" as the idea, here.

@AhmedTawfik Part of the difficulty with your question is that the US already passed a law nicknamed the "Invade the Hague Act". Further, ICC jurisdiction here is contentious. There is no state of Palestine. Gaza and the West Bank are claimed by Israel, so the ICC is involving itself in a territorial dispute against the US and Israel, which it has no authority over. There is a lot of political dispute to "side with" to provide an answer to this question. Some people may think that shows a lack of research, that it may be pushing a specific ideology, or that the question cannot be answered.

@DavidS The way I saw this is an international act of intimidation. Regardless of jurisdiction etc, I think some of the answers here referencing "rules-based order" are closer to answering the spirit of the question. Although, I don't intend to mark a specific answer as accepted to avoid bias...

Abuse of power by whom? In 10/20/30/50/100 years from now history and random internet people will argue about how the ICC equated Israel with the most evil people on the planet. The taint will never go away - if it is allowed to occur. That a few US Senators are trying to remind a specific group to reconsider their actions. There are consequences for outrageous behaviour is a reasonable reminder by the US senate, even if it is just travel bans.

@DogBoy37 Of course, they're being very reasonable and gentle :)

It isn't illegal under U.S. law (due to the Speech and Debate Clause of Article I of the U.S. Constitution). But, it isn't clear what is meant by "abuse of power." If the question is whether it is illegal, the answer is no under U.S. law, and international law doesn't really have any binding provisions on point. If the question is whether it is a breech of diplomatic etiquette or morally improper, who knows?

@ohwilleke a fairly strong case can be made that the US Servicemen Protection Act makes ICC officials subjects of the US law.  So they may not enjoy any diplomatic immunity w.r.t. the US law.  Diplomatic etiquette exists in order to navigate the gray space between diplomats who generally operate outside of laws.

The threat is plausible, because both US Congress and the US Executive branch have already taken the actions which are threatened in this letter, in previous circumstances.
In 2002, US Congress passed a law and President Bush signed it, the American Service Members Protection Act. Per this law, jurists and prosecutors of the ICC would be sanctioned if the ICC takes action against service members or officials, of both the US and of allied countries (such as Israel in this case).
In 2020, the US Executive branch exercised the power granted to it by the above law. Sanctions were imposed by the US Treasury Department against the chief prosecutor of the ICC.

Regarding abuse of power - the ICC itself has made an initial response, as quoted in the Question. Threats against the court may themselves constitute an offence. On the matter of jurisdiction, it's true that the US withdrew its signature of the Rome Statute in 2002. However, jurisdiction is determined not by the membership of the offending country, but by the membership of the country on whose territory the alleged offence took place (in the preceding link, scroll down to the section on "Jurisdiction"). This is certainly relevant to acts of violence (e.g. ethnic cleansing and war crimes) committed by non signatories.
When talking about threats against the court, there is perhaps some wiggle room in jurisdiction regarding the threats themselves, but it is without a doubt that such threats on their face attempt to undermine international law, and will rightly be seen as such.

Is this not Congress saying to the ICC, "You don't have any authority over Israel"? I have checked and this is true; the ICC has no authority over Israel.

@Joshua No Congress is clearly not saying 'The ICC has no authority over Israel', they are saying 'Target Israel, and we will target you'. This is no argument about who has or hasn't authority, this is a direct threat with power.

@quarague the American Service Members Protection Act already makes this threat because it authorizes use of force to forestall any action taken against US service members or US allies.  Further, because in so doing it imposes legal restrictions on the ICC officials, it makes ICC officials subjects of the US law.  Which strips them of any diplomatic status wrt to the US.

Just to be clear, while Congress could impose sanctions of some sort against the ICC or its members, it is extremely unlikely to do so, this small cohort of congresspeople notwithstanding. The ICC is highly regarded, and any sanctions would invariably be seen as expressly political and detrimental to world order. This letter seems to be entirely a matter of political grandstanding which will not advance to any actionable resolution or bill. It's meant to play as drama to a conservative domestic audience, by people who don't much care about international diplomatic repercussions.
As to whether it might be an abuse of power… There is currently no meaningful definition of 'abuse of power' for congresspeople, at least none that will lead to any consequences. I could argue that it's demonstrably unethical, but that would lead me back to a snide comment I read in a novel once: that if you asked these people if they had any scruples, they'd say no, but that they might be able to get you some for the right price.

While I fully agree with the last sentence of your first paragraph, I'm not sure how you conclude that these threats are unlikely to be carried through, especially so if Trump wins the election.

If the ICC acts outside of its authorized mandate, it would be appropriate and necessary to take actions to sanction it.  Any ICC action against government officials of the US, Israel, or any other country with laws against war crimes, or other atrocities, would be a violation of the court's complementarity provided that the country in question has an independent judiciary with a history of checking government actions.  Maintaining the court's complementarity (article 17 of the Rome Statute) is a requirement that the ICC may not ignore.

@wrod: The US is not a signatory to the ICC, so technically speaking the US has no say whatsoever in what the ICC does. If it were a signatory it could contest decisions directly; as a non-signatory it could petition a signatory to act on its behalf, but otherwise… And note. that's an awfully big 'if' on the front of your post.

@TedWrigley that is simply untrue.  People with no formal connection to a court may brief it on their opinions if they can get the court's ear.  This isn't just true of the ICC.  It's true of many courts.

The ICC is highly regarded => by whom? The general public? Of what country?

@JonathanReez Well, on a 2020 poll, by a Jewish pro-peace organization in Canada:  When the question specifically asked if the ICC should investigate alleged war crimes committed
by Israeli officials, 84% of Canadians agreed, and 16% responded “no.”  Again, let's not run ahead of ourselves and presume guilt or even grounds for indictment.  Merely... is it proper to nip investigations in the bud just because Israel is involved (assuming the ICC is impartial in its work)?

@wrod That's not how complementarity works in the Rome statute. The State must have investigated this particular case and even then there are caveats.

@TedWrigley On the other hand, the US has proven quite willing to undermine the court, most notably under Trump but not only without much apparent concern for the international legal order or diplomatic credibility.


what are the implications of this letter - does it pose legitimate threat, or is it an empty threat?

It is a legitimate act on behalf of the US Senators. It is not a threat, but rather a reminder of duties and obligations of the International Criminal Court (ICC).

And if it were legitimate, would it be an abuse of power by the US Senate?

No, it would not be an abuse of power by the US Senate.
The 3 key elements of the abuse of power are:

Misuse of a position of power.
Taking unjust advantage of individuals and organizations.
Deceit.

None of these have taken place. Indeed:

Writing a letter regarding the future of the US support of an organization such as ICC, or sanctions against specific individuals within ICC is within the purview of the US Senate, as defined by the laws of the United States.
US Senate is not taking un unjust advantage of the ICC. The US Senate is free to start or stop supporting ICC, and free to issue sanctions against specific ICC individuals. Doing the reverse would in fact be unjust, namely supporting the organizations and allowing into the US individuals that undermine the security of Israel and thus aid and abet Hamas, a known terrorist organization. ICC has a long history of selective application of justice and misuse of the justice system.
The US Senate does not engage is deceit here. On the contrary, it seeks maximum transparency by openly stating the reasons of the potential sanctions and withdrawal of support.

References

A simple definition of the abuse of power is the misuse of a position of power to take unjust advantage of individuals, organizations, or governments. Abuses of power have been variously described as white-collar crime, economic crime, organizational crime, occupational crime, public corruption, organized crime, and governmental and corporate deviance. The common element of these crimes is deceit.

Crime and the Abuse of Power - Offenses and Offenders Beyond the Reach of Law? | Office of Justice Programs


Following his visit, [Karim Khan] said that the ICC was investigating the crimes against Israeli civilians as “some of the most serious international crimes that shock the conscience of humanity.”


In 2021, then-chief prosecutor Fatouh Bensouda announced that she was opening an investigation into possible crimes in the West Bank and the Gaza Strip. That investigation will examine the region but controversially starting from June 13, 2014 — one day after Palestinian terrorists kidnapped and murdered three Israeli teenagers in the West Bank, meaning the ICC will not look into the crimes that sparked Israel’s war in Gaza that summer.
Israel often levels accusations of bias at the UN and international bodies, and Netanyahu slammed the decision to probe “fake war crimes” as hypocritical and antisemitic.

ICC prosecutor slams effort to 'intimidate' him on possible arrest warrants for Israelis | The Times of Israel


Note: The leaders of Iran, Syria, and Hamas have not been prosecuted by ICC for terrorism and mass killings of civilians. But ICC considers selectively prosecuting the leaders of Israel, who act to secure Israeli civilians against further terrorist attacks, similar to the one on October 7, 2023.
Evan Dyer @EvanDyerCBC, 11:43 AM · May 6, 2024


The US-ICC Relationship
The United States (US) historically has been and continues to be an an ardent supporter of international criminal justice, having played critical roles in the establishment and operations of the United Nations (UN) War Crimes Commission, the World War II tribunals at Nuremberg and Tokyo, and the modern UN ad hoc and hybrid international tribunals for the former Yugoslavia, Rwanda, Sierra Leone, Cambodia, Lebanon and others. The International Criminal Court (ICC), the only permanent international criminal tribunal with a mandate to investigate and prosecute the international atrocity crimes of genocide, crimes against humanity, war crimes, and aggression, is the cornerstone of the system of international criminal justice.
At present 123 nations have ratified the Rome Statute and are members of the ICC Assembly of States Parties. While the United States played a central role in the establishment of the Rome Statute that created the ICC, the United States is not a State Party. Building upon positive developments at the end of the George W. Bush administration, the US-ICC relationship significantly progressed during the Barack Obama administration, with the US providing varied and important support to the Court to the fullest extent allowed under existing US law. However, the policies of the Donald Trump administration highlighted a much more complicated relationship between the Untied States and the ICC.

The US-ICC Relationship | International Criminal Court Project

Abuse of Power

Abuse of power or abuse of authority, in the form of "malfeasance in office" or "official abuse of power", is the commission of an unlawful act, done in an official capacity, which affects the performance of official duties.

How is this act unlawful, from a US PoV? Congress does as it likes, within US laws.  US senators are well within their rights to state their opinions and goals, including on foreign policy.
Even in other countries like France or Canada, such claims, made in parliament, would probably see them benefiting from parliamentary immunity.  Unless there was an outcry and that legislator was booted out by their peers and/or constituents.
On the flip side, this USA-uber-alles attitude, while red meat to the faithful, is also cyanide to the "rules-based order" the US claims to hold as a foreign policy goal.  It is especially laughable after US supporting the same ICC against Putin. This is true now, it was also true when the same US threatened the ICC in case its service members ever got investigated.  Or sanctioned some of them, under the Trump administration.
This is not particularly beneficial to long term US foreign policy goals and building support against autocratic nations like China or Russia.  Republicans eager to provide cover for their ally may want to consider that.  The Ukraine war has made apparent how little patience the non-Western world has for states that say one thing but at least seem to act the opposite ("No, Libya was nothing like Ukraine!" *).
ICC proceedings, if they happen, in the case of Israel should be decided only by the actual facts of the matter.  Not driven by the well-known bias against Israel in some parts of the international community.  But not hindered either by threats from a country that is neither a member, nor a contributor, to the ICC but mostly supports the ICC when it suits them best.
It is also useful to remember that an indictment, while embarrassing, is not the same as a conviction.  In fact, if Israel is as respectful of IHL as it claims, a case could "air things out" and let it disprove its detractors.
However, bear in mind that these people are not all that representative of US foreign policy under the Biden administration and, again, mostly are acting for domestic electoral reasons.  Best to remember that Cruz, for example, is a loon: this is a man who rules out abortion in case of rape and incest.  Also, good to remember, for critics of Biden's support of Israel, that under Trump 2, this might very well graduate from legislative branch member's opinion to executive branch policy.
Last, while the ICC is correct to protest against these threats and pressures, it would seem highly unproductive for them to take action, via "ICC channels", against those senators.

“Such threats, even not acted upon, may constitute an offence”

Also, the senators in question aren't wrong to question why Syria's al-Assad isn't already the beneficiary of an arrest warrant.
* I myself don't think Lybia and Ukraine are much alike, but the arguments for intervening in Lybia are complex and, in hindsight, judging by the outcome for Lybians, not all that clearcut.  Ukraine is very clearcut:  aggression on a neighbor that dared stray from Russia's diktat.

a case could "air things out" and let it disprove its detractors => this ignore the fact that often times the process is itself a form of punishment. I.e. if you were to be put on a trial for a murder you didn't commit, I don't think you'd be appreciate the opportunity to "disprove your detractors". You'd instead prefer to never be threatened by the system in the first place.

@JonathanReez True, but if you insist on analogies, the US seems to be pressuring the AG not to indict its good buddy.  Now, I dunno if there are sufficient grounds to investigate or not.  But I will say that the atrocities of 10/7, and Israel's right to defend itself are orthogonal to still having to respect IHL regardless.  Booting Hamas from Gaza is one thing.  High levels of dead civilians is another and may not have been avoidable given the urban context and Hamas efforts.  Respecting laws of war is still required.  If we trust ICC on other cases, let them do their work here too.

Unnecessary attacks based on completely unrelated topics detract from this answer.

@BenVoigt Do they?  I put them there, because at least on one metric, women's rights, Cruz is very much a politician with extreme views.  Such extremes are there throughout his worldview, not least to anything he remotely considers socialist in nature.  Rest assured, when I criticized an answer for citing Rashida Tlaib with regards to ICC procedures, with her well-known anti-Israel bias, had she had equivalent "unrelated topics" in her closet, I'd also have cited them to remind readers whom they were dealing with.
